# Importing SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to know if is there a way to import the whole SQL Server 2008 instance from one computer to another, including master and other databases, instead of installing a new instance from the scratch.

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. please explain with some more information

Comment: What i need is to do a certain backup from existing instance, and the re use it in another computer, which has already sql server 2008 installed

Comment: Can't you just backup your database on one computer, and restore it on the other, if SQL Server 2008 is already installed?

Comment: Other databases is trivial, Master is a more complex operation, server name is in there for instance. Why do you think you need Master?

Comment: you are asking if sql server is somewhat 'portable'?

Comment: I need Master because it contains informations of users, and all databases configurations

Comment: @Paolo yes that's it

Comment: See [this answer][1] on DBA. Same thing but for SQL 2008 R2.


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/migrating-from-one-sql-server-2008-r2-instance-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You need to create backups for all the database given in the instance and then restore it into the newer one instance.

This could be one the way, can use.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier, if you had VM backup of the SQL Server instance. You could then restore the veeam backup